# Why is it acceptable to initialize a Priority Queue from primitive Data Structure in Java?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures

This could should not compile because of initializing Generic Class using primitive datatype but it does.

```java
public int[] topKFrequent(int[] nums, int k) {
    PriorityQueue<int[]> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(
            (a, b) -> a[1] == b[1] ? b[0] - a[0] : b[1] - a[1]);
    int[] arr = new int[20001];
    for (int num : nums) arr[num + 10000]++;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20001; i++)
        if (arr[i] != 0) priorityQueue.add(new int[]{i - 10000, arr[i]});
    int length = Math.min(priorityQueue.size(), k);
    int[] result = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) result[i] = priorityQueue.poll()[0];
    return result;
}
```

As per [Java Documentation on Java Generics Restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html), you cannot instantiate a Generic Datatype from a primitive datatype.

So how come the aforementioned code compiles?

I am using java 8 (1.8.xx) SDE.

Comment: `int[]` is not a primitive datatype.

Comment: `int` is a primitive data type, `int[]` is not.

Comment: because you are having a priority queue of int arrays. ie --> `{[...], [...], [...], [...]}` rather than `{...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, `int[]` and arrays of any primitive data types are not primitives.

Primitive data types are the only ones mentioned in [Java SE Primitive Data Types Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).